# Rounding to no decimal places (value is returned with 10 decimal places?)

Tags: java, android

So, I have this code implemented and working:

```
try {
        float healthF = Float.parseFloat(getHealth);
        healthchest.setText(Float.toString((healthF * 100) * 0.30f));
    }
```

But the value it returns has about 10 decimal places with a 6 randomly placed at the end. Something akin to this: ###.0000000006. The weird thing is the value of healthF is 30. 3000 * .3 equals 900. Not 900.0000000006.

I tried to implement this:

```
try {
        float healthF = Float.parseFloat(getHealth);
        healthchest.setText(Float.toString((healthF * 100) * 0.30f));
        df.format(healthchest);
    }
```

but it causes the app to crash with the following logcat:

```
09-03 03:26:54.755: W/dalvikvm(1080): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mikitz.rogsimple/com.mikitz.rogsimple.ArmorStatsSP}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class android.widget.EditText
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class android.widget.EditText
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at java.text.NumberFormat.format(NumberFormat.java:304)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:702)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at com.mikitz.rogsimple.ArmorStatsSP.onCreate(ArmorStatsSP.java:78)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-03 03:26:54.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Use NumberFormat for formatting numbers

Comment: Read Appendix D: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the edittext to the DecimalFormat, use the following method and pass the value to it, than set the string returned to the edittext.

```
 public static String twoDecimalPlaces(double value){
            try 
            {
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
                return df.format(value);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogHandler.error("twoDecimalPlaces","main",e);
            }
            return String.valueOf(value);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
Float floatValue = 1.454f;
String.format("%.0f",floatValue);
```

Comment: While this didn't crash the app, it did nothing. I did try to use this: `String.format("%.0f", healthchest);` which crashed the app.